# innerHTML won't change in each keydown event

Tags: javascript, html, greasemonkey

The following code is aimed to change the innerHTML of an element (`myNote`) to the value of another element (`myInput`), **each time** the ***Return*** key is pressed:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name        Duolingo
// @include     *://duolingo.com/*
// @include     *://www.duolingo.com/*
// ==/UserScript==
setTimeout(()=>{
  let myInput = document.querySelector('._7q434._1qCW5._2fPEB._3_NyK._1Juqt._3WbPm');
  let myNote = document.createElement('div');
  document.body.appendChild(myNote);
  myNote.setAttribute("style", "position: fixed; bottom: 0; right: 0; display: block; width: 400px; height: 400px; background: orange; color: #000");

  myInput.addEventListener('keydown', (k)=>{
    if ( k.keyCode === 13 ) {
      myNote.innerHTML += myInput.value + '<br>';
    }
  });
}, 2000);
```

### Purpose

I run the code in Greasemonkey on [duolingo.com](http://duolingo.com) (a site for learning mind2mind languages like French), in textual question sessions like "translate this sentence".

The code's purpose is to create a small orange-background box containing the inputs I already tried in Duolingo questions, given that Duolingo doesn't save these.

With the script, I could save them and later use them if I retake a language question as it saves me some time retyping most of a sentence.

### Problem

The code fails because the `innerHTML` is changed only once. If the value changes again and I repress ***Return***, nothing will happen.

### Reproduce

Reproduce by using the code in Greasemonkey (or a similar program) on duolingo.com.

### Question

Why would the `innerHTML` be changed only once? Given the `addEventListener` listens all the time, why it'll work only once?

Using `return` for the change or adding `return false` didn't help.

Maybe another approach of adding a new element containing the value each pressing is needed.

### Update for Mobius:

Mobius, this is the code I used, which didn't work:

```
setTimeout(()=>{
    window.myCss =`.note {position: fixed; bottom: 0; right: 0; width: 400px; height: 400px; background: orange}`;
    style = document.createElement("style");
    style.type = "text/css";
    style.styleSheet ? style.styleSheet.cssText = myCss : style.appendChild(document.createTextNode(myCss) );
    head = document.head || document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0];
    head.appendChild(style);

    let note = document.createElement('div');
    note.classList.add('note');
    document.querySelector('body').appendChild(note);

  let savedValue;
    document.addEventListener('keydown', (e)=>{
    let target = e.target;
    if (target.nodeName === 'textarea') {
        savedValue = e.target.value;
        }
    });

    if (k.keyCode === 13) {
        setTimeout(()=>{
            document.querySelector('textarea').value = savedValue;
        }, 100);
    }
}, 2500);
```

I didn't have any error in console.

I tried to read in the article and I understand that in the original example I babbled instead of captured (and I should capture any handler by going from the `html` element to my `textarea` element each time anew and capture it's handler, but I couldn't see how to improve the code from that. Maybe I didn't read good as I'm in a bad mood right now...

Comment: I should note that replacing `myNote` to `document` so to get `document.addEventListener` also didn't help.

Comment: Because that was the first big problem, but not the only one. See my updated answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code fails (after removing the typo) because it adds the event listener to a textarea that **the webpage overwrites with every new question**.  When the textarea is overwritten, it destroys the previous event listener that you added.  It also orphans the value of `myInput` in that code.

Use a smarter event listener on a persistent container or the whole body. And, refresh `myInput` as needed.

There are other issues:

1. `._7q434._1qCW5._2fPEB._3_NyK._1Juqt._3WbPm` **is an exceptionally brittle selector** and will break the next time the website code changes.  It also already doesn't work on some pages I saw.

   `textarea[data-test]` will probably work.  Or even `textarea` might suffice given the rest of the code.
2. `setTimeout` is a brittle way to wait for elements and is [already causing you grief](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46868819/function-call-fails-in-running-the-desired-functionality-again).  Use `waitForKeyElements`, or `MutationObserver` or similar instead.  But in your case, since you are waiting for user interaction, **you probably do not need any other delay** mechanism.

Putting that all together, your userscript would be something like:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name        Duolingo, answer text recycler
// @match       *://*.duolingo.com/*
// @run-at      document-idle
// ==/UserScript==
let myNote = document.createElement ('div');
document.body.appendChild (myNote);
myNote.setAttribute (
    "style",
    "position: fixed; bottom: 0; right: 0; width: 400px; height: 400px; background: orange; overflow: auto;"
);

document.addEventListener ('keydown', (zEvent) => {
    if (zEvent.keyCode === 13) {
        if (zEvent.target.nodeName === 'TEXTAREA') {
            let myInput = document.querySelector ('textarea[data-test]');
            if (myInput) {
                myNote.innerHTML += myInput.value + '<br>';
            }
        }
    }
} );
```

Comment: Deep thanks! I want to ask you only this: Is the z in zEvent has a special meaning (just to understand the naming). And, what is the meaning of `if (myInput) {`?

Comment: `z` is a useful holdover from "Hungarian notation".  It makes code maintenance easier as "event" is a massively overloaded and common word. ... `if (myInput) {` keeps the code running in the unlikely event that the element was not found.  in fact, you should test the result *every* time that you use `querySelector()` or similar.

Comment: I understand these now and I also have a better understanding of the importance of keeping clear from large automatic slectors like `._7q434._1qCW5._2fPEB._3_NyK._1Juqt._3WbPm` and preferring giving a basic element type to target `TEXTAREA`, and using this elements **attributes** as in `('textarea[data-test]');`.

Comment: I will try it very soon, I want to read it one more time before trying it just in principle. When someone shows me a working script I always make sure I read it at least 2 times and discuss it to make sure I understand everything in it and not working with something I don't understand well enough.

Comment: Indeed it worked and I've learned much. I thank you deeply for this help. I'll save this code well and have internalized an interesting principle from it: A basic reference to the event target (the event's associated element) must first include a general reference to the type of that target (`if (zEvent.target.nodeName === 'TEXTAREA')`, and only then, a local, more specific reference (`let myInput = document.querySelector ('textarea[data-test]')`).

Answer (score 2):

The quizzes in duolingo are written in react as far as i can tell, for this reason it is very likely that the element you added the event listener to no longer exists. There are several ways around this, but the best is probably using event bubbling (probably on the capture phase) to listen on something that won't get replaced such as the `body` element and wait for events that come from an element that matches your needs.

your code will look something like this:

```
let savedValue = '';
document.addEventListener('keydown', (e) => {
    let target = e.target;
    if (target.nodeName == 'TEXTAREA') {
        // save off the text value;
        savedValue = e.target.value;
    }

    if (e.keyCode == 13){
        setTimeout(() => { 
            document.querySelector('textarea').value = savedValue;
        }, 10);
    }
}, true)
```

Comment: @Benia the class you have there is generated by the build server as part of using CSS-Modules, so it will change every time they push an update. You may wish to use something else like a data attribute for the selector.

Comment: I gladly offer bounty now. Please don't hesitate to detail more somewhere if you see fit, and also, please use this selector because this selector doesn't change (I double checked that): `._7q434._1qCW5._2fPEB._3_NyK._1Juqt._3WbPm`.

Comment: AFAIU from your answer, there are two types of event listening in JS: ***Global*** listening (like to **all** input[type="textarea"] or **all** elements with the class combination `._7q434._1qCW5._2fPEB._3_NyK._1Juqt._3WbPm`), while what I did originally was ***specific*** listening (just for the **first** element of that kind and not all ones in the document globally. Is that correct? If so, it sounds quite like the difference between `querySelector` and `querySelectorAll`...

Comment: I'll gladly give you the bounty @Mobius I just desire to know if I was accurate in how I understood you.

Comment: @Benia, Event capturing has to do with the fact that many events can be captured at a higher container level before they actually fire the event handler for the element itself. When we listen for the event at the `document` level, we can see any `keydown` event that happens for any element inside that container. Since we only care about the textarea, we are using the `nodeName` to limit it to events that come from text areas, you could do this differently, but I think this works fine.

Comment: Hmm, reading twice I think I described it right above. Window or Document eventListening are global and occur for all such elements while a eventListening for a specific element is for the first instance of that element (either if there are more instances created without the original one deleted or if the original is deleted and replaced in a another exactly similar), to put it more simply --- just once for that element.

Comment: the difference is that you can add a listener to _any_ parent of the element, not just the `document.body`. The reason I chose `document.body` is because it's the parent of the react root node.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/Events#Event_bubbling_and_capture

Comment: Mobius I updated the question. Sorry if you feel we overtalk this. I will understand if you no longer wish to reply about this. I might need to pay for a senior programmer to learn this from him in a ordered way because I'm in a bad mood in these days and can't concatenate well at this time. I did try another code based on your example and wrote the main things I recognized in the article you linked to.

Answer (score 0):

```js
// ==UserScript==
// @name        Duolingo
// @namespace   nms
// @include     *://duolingo.com/*
// @include     *://www.duolingo.com/*
// @version     1
// @grant       none
// ==/UserScript==

setTimeout(()=>{
    // Style:

        /*let myCss =`
            .note {position: fixed; bottom: 0; right: 0; width: 400px; height: 400px; background: orange}
        `;*/
      let myCss =`
            .note {position: fixed; top: 100px; left:100px; bottom: 100px; right: 100px; width: 200px; height: 200px; background: orange}
        `;  

        style = document.createElement("style");
        style.type = "text/css";
        style.styleSheet ? style.styleSheet.cssText = myCss : style.appendChild(document.createTextNode(myCss) );

        head = document.head || document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0];
        head.appendChild(style);

    // Behavior:

        let myNote = document.createElement('div');
        myNote.classList.add('note');
        document.querySelector('body').appendChild(myNote);
        let myInputField = document.querySelector('textarea');

        myInputField.addEventListener('keydown', (k)=>{
            if ( k.keyCode === 13 ) {
                myNote.innerHTML = myInputField.value;
            }
        });
}, 2000);
```

```html
<textarea></textarea>
<br>
<div id="myNote">

</div>
```

If you run the original code in full page view on StackOverflow, the code runs fine.  I altered the css for the orange rectangle to see the results better in the non-full page view and it works, too. Note: I am using Google Chrome Version 49.0.2623.112 m.